# widget logic multiple option not working

Tags: wordpress, widget

I am using the widget logic plugin now in my wordpress theme. I want to use a widget in different widget. For example I want not to use the widget in home page and the "about" inner page. So I wrote the following thing to disable the widgets in those pages.

```
!is_front_page() || !is_page('about')
```

But I could not get the result by the code. Is there any problem with my code or is there any other way to get the widget in particular page.

The widgets are enable with the widget logic code or not. Please help me to get the result.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it shouldn't be `||` it should be `&&` - what you've done will always resolve as true.

Comment: Thank you, Actually i did it previously, but i dont know why it was not work. It is ok now.